# Should one inherit GUI JFrames?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I've a `JFrame` `'A'` and I'd like to provide a very similar one, but with extra buttons, and different functionality. I was wondering if I should inherit `'A'` and then overwrite the handler methods, and add components, or whether a different approach is recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would prefer inheriting JPanels. I find that the reuse aspect leans more towards using the UI Panels and reusing those.

The way I build my Swing UIs is to have a JFrame and have it use a panel that is composed of  reusable panels if they share common functionality.

If you have a JFrame that shares common functionality then you might want to create one with a given CloseHandler and other common code and then have your other Jframes inherit from that common one.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer composition over inheritence in most cases. In this case it depends on how much code there is in A. You could either use a Strategy pattern for the variability points in the code, but in most cases inheritence will be the least ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is the best way here.

Honestly, doing it another way would involve a *lot* of work.